# Is there a Low-Def HDMI monitor for Raspberry be that is not more expensive that RPi itself?

Tags: hdmi, display

There is [HDMI Pi](http://hdmipi.com/), a "1280x800 Affordable *High-Def* HDMI screen for Raspbery Pi", but I feel it would be still even more expesive than the RPi itself.

Are there Low-Def 480x320-ish **HDMI** screens that are more like 20 USD?

I expect it to be of the size of RPi itself, be powered from 3.3 or 5V and consume up to 0.5 amperes. The main purpose is seeing what is happening on HDMI (for debugging) when TV-set or monitor (or power for it) is far away.

Comment: I don't think you'll ever find a HDMI screen which is cheaper than the RPi itself. Correct me if I'm wrong, but in your video a laptop screen is salvaged and connected to the RPi via an HDMI to LVDS converter board, so the price of the screen itself is not even factored in. Nice video btw!

Answer (score 1):

Adafruit has several displays in the $30-45 range which connect to the Pi via SPI. Many of them include a touchscreen.

This 320x240 2.8" touchscreen for $35: http://www.adafruit.com/products/1601

This 480x320 3.5" touchscreen for $45: http://www.adafruit.com/products/2097

Comment: I know there are such displays for RPi. I specifically ask for **HDMI** one. The main purpose is actually not bring a display to RPi, but to have a cheap and little tool for accessing HDMI (not only from RPi, but from whatever).

Comment: Ah, well, then I think the answer is no, AFAIK.